# Consistency in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

Does in AP of the CAP theorm, is there a possibility (like in cassandra), that if i write/update to cassandra and immediately try to fetch it, can there a chance the data is not found or should my read o/p be paused before being fetched (hence allowing replications to settle in).

Can someone direct me to any link where people have addressed the consistency issue in cassandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra can be used to give the consistency that you describe.  If the number of nodes you read from (R) plus the number of nodes you write to (W) is greater than the replication factor (N), you will read back a value immediately after it was written (assuming there are no concurrent writers who may write a later value in the small window since you wrote).  So as long as R+W>N you will get this behaviour.

A common way to do this is to read and write at CL.QUORUM, since this gives you good availability.  You could also e.g. read at CL.ONE and write at CL.ALL, but then writes will fail if a single node is down.